# Cannot change a variable(score) dynamically in python

Tags: python, function, variables, global-variables, args

My program objective:
A dice game, two dice roll Everytime the player is ready. If the two numbers are equa, player gets +5 score. Else, -1 score.
My trouble: my program can't change the score. It is set to 0 initially. But Everytime it's only either -1 or +5. It has to keep decreasing or increasing. I also tried global variables.
Here is my code:

```
from random import randint
    
    
# this function returns two random numbers in list as dice result.
def roll_dice():
    dice1 = randint(1, 7)
    dice2 = randint(1, 7)
    rolled_dice = [dice1, dice2]
    return rolled_dice
    
    
# game function is all the game, if player is ready.
def game():
    score = 0
    rolled_dice = roll_dice()
    print(rolled_dice)
    if rolled_dice[0] != rolled_dice[1]:
        score -= 1
    elif rolled_dice[0] == rolled_dice[1]:
        score += 5
    print(f"score is {score}")
#also my code in pycharms, not asking if I want to continue game. but ignore it I it bothers you, I can figure it out.
    #help here also if you can.. :)

    conti = input("continue?")
    if conti == 'y':
        game()
    else:
        quit()
    
    
# this is the whole program.
def main():
    ready = input("ready? (y/n)")
    if ready == 'y':
        game()
    elif ready == 'n':
        quit()
    else:
        print("type only y/n")
    
main()
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reset happens because you keep calling your *game()* function each time a user types *y* to continue the game. You can change your *game()* function to be a loop and that will solve your problem:

```
def game():
    score = 0
    while True:
        rolled_dice = roll_dice()
        print(rolled_dice)
        if rolled_dice[0] != rolled_dice[1]:
            score -= 1
        else: # you can change here to else, because being equals is the complement of the first if clause
            score += 5
        print(f"score is {score}")

        conti = input("continue?")
        if conti == 'n':
            break
```